# Application crash on _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext

Tags: ios, swift, exception

I'm working on iOS application in Swift. I have a strange crash and I can't figure out on which line of code it crashes or what caused it. I set All Exceptions breakpoint in Xcode 7.2 but without luck. There is no log, only this: `-[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:]` In screenshot below you can see exception where the application breaks.

[Application crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtZtU.png)

Can someone please help me solve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any crash message ? appear in console ? please put some code .

Comment: No, there is no crash messages... I'm implementing chat, and using layer framework. When I load application after log in and open chat conversation and put app in background, after that, i launched it again by icon tap. Then this exception occurs. I would provide some code but I don't know which part of it to paste...